# How synchronization works?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

For example I have  @Stateless java bean:

```java
@Stateless(mappedName = "test") 
public class Test implements ITest
{
    @Override
    public void updateActivity
      (SomeObj activity)
      throws Exception
    {
        em.persist(activity);
    } 
}
```

Because it's a container-managed bean, then tell me, when does the container decide to synchronize the context with a DB? In this case I immediately see the results in the DB, but sometimes they do not seem to immediately appear there, right?

Please explain me How the synchronization works with the context and the DB at Container-Managed mode? When does the container decide to synchronize the context with a DB?

Comment: You want to say that in this case it is always immediately will be save in the database?

Comment: I'd say this depends on your transactional scope and on the method you look into the database. If the transaction is container managed it will be persistent in your database as soon as the transaction commits. In the container managed case this is when your call into the container exits. If you look into your database with and turn on READ UNCOMMITED  you will even see changes that are not yet commited.

Comment: @cmoetzing  "as soon as the transaction commits"  When? When will it be commit ? When does the container decide to commit object to DB? (if class and method doesn't have TransactionAttribute annotation? )

Comment: @cmoetzing Sorry, What you mean ? ("In the container managed case this is when your call into the container exits") I don't undestand, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

This will be driven by the [transaction propagation](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/Java/archives/0504/tyagi/index.html) configuration as your EJB bean might be one of many managed beans participating in a single transaction. This gets more complex if there are multiple transaction sources in flight e.g. [XA 2PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). Generally, the changes will be flushed into the database on transaction commit however this further depends on the [transaction isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) or the presence of [savepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savepoint) when nested transactions are used.

Check the [`@TransactionAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) annotation docs or look for a [tutorial](https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-ejb-transaction-propagation-transactionattribute-tutorial) that explains transaction propagation.

Comment: Karol! Yes, I know about TransactionAttribute annotation. But My question about when bean and method doesn't have TransactionAttribute annotation. How container works in the my sample? When does the container decide to commit object to DB?

Comment: @denisaaa08 This information is all available in the documentation. Please follow the information given by @KarolDowbecki. Both `TransactionManagement` and `@TransactionAttribute` have [default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionManagement.html). Just because you do not declare it does not mean it is not configured. You enter your container when you click on a button in the UI for example. The transaction will be committed before the new page will be rendered as reaction to your click.